# I don't know why I am getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null"

Tags: reactjs, typeerror

I am getting the error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null

```
var highScoresList = document.getElementById("highScoresList");
var highScores = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("highScores")) || [];


highScoresList.innerHTML = highScores
  .map(score => {
    return `<li class="high-score>${score.name}-${score.score}</li>`;
  })
  .join("");
```

Comment: LocalStorage.getItem("highScores") is returning null, try changing line 2 to

var highScores = localStorage.getItem("highScores") ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("highScores")) : [];

Comment: your local storage  does not have highScores. you need a null check